# Test IAP in simulator - react-native?

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I use react-native-iap, And I have `Non-Consumable` so I use `getAvailablePurchases()` but in every time I get this error

> `Cannot connect to iTunes Store`

So I can't test what I do while developing or if the user buying successfully or not or what the result of data should return when using getAvilablePurchases() or other methods

So is there a way to solve this issue?

[image: app store]

[Screen](https://m.imgur.com/CCTnIhs)

Code

```
const items = Platform.select({
     ios:"com.myapp.premium"
  });

export default class PurchaseScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPurchases();
  }
  getPurchases = async () => {
    try {
      const init = await RNIap.initConnection();
      console.log('init?', init);
      const availablePurchases = await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases(items);
      console.log('availablePurchases', availablePurchases);
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };


subscribe = ()=>{
    ...
}

  render() {
    return (

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.subscribe()} style={styles.btn}>
       <Text style={styles.lable}>Subscrib</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   )
  }

}
```

Comment: @dan10gc Hey, Daniel this the original question!

Answer (score 3):

**You can't test in app purchases in the simulator.**

However you will be able to get list of products ([SKProduct]).

Comment: Well, now I don't have a real device and our city is a lockdown, so I have a friend but not Tech, so how can I use his mobile in this case? Can I connect to it from any app or something to use it in Xcode?

Comment: you can publish app on Testflight and invite your friend to testing. He can test your inapp in the sandbox. 
But this is take a lot of time and this is not informative for debug.

Comment: Also your friend can send his device by post:)

Comment: I'm from Palestine :) we don't have a Post office in my city..

Comment: You can try services that provide access to real devices online. Google it. 
First I found - is https://www.browserstack.com/. As I understand, you can test InApp here (https://www.browserstack.com/app-live/native-device-features#apple-in-app-purchase). This is paid service, maybe you can find free or use this but trial.
But also you can't do it from XCode - just make build and upload to site. Anyway this is better than nothing. You can display your debug data to some alerts, ets. 
@OliverD

Comment: @Alex is "Status/Missing metadata" good enough to get the product? I was able to log in with sandbox account in iOS Simulator, but RN app rejects Promise "Invalid product ID". Do I have to build the UI and upload screenshot?

Comment: At first please ensure that you have setup all Agreements,Tax,Banking section:
1. have active paid agreement http://joxi.ru/8AnXQx4uzwGPnm
2. have form http://joxi.ru/brRDBa3s7NzlG2 on Tax
3. have completely configured bank account http://joxi.ru/eAOqbLZu9dj5Rm on Banking
4. Have an adress in http://joxi.ru/LmGVbaYfwv9oqr Contacts

For me these items were reason of "Invalid product ID" error.

Then
Make sure that your metadata is set completely: product id, name, description for at least one localisation, screenshot.

Comment: However even you has Missing metadata - in most cases, you will be able to get products.

Trick - if you have setup products completely and still get "missing metadata" error - just add any new localisation (Canada for example) with name and description.

So, I had a "Missing metadata" statuses, but could to get products (but with empty localised description)

Comment: @DavideValdo, also, send your app to review (without release) and don't forget to include your inappurchases in the "new version" page.